# C Passing a struct, that contains a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Im trying to An array of structs which is contained inside another Struct
EG (Struct1.StructArray[])

The code looks like the following:

```
struct bullet{
    int x;
    int y;
    int exist;
    int type;
};

struct tank{
    int x;
    int alive;
    int shotsfired;
    struct bullet shots[50];
};
```

Im trying to Pass Just the shots[] Struct as a pointer to the following function.

```
int get_alien_collision(struct bullet *bulletStruct)
```

The Line Of code Im using to pass the struct is as follows.

```
a = get_alien_collision(&player.shots[i])
```

I am unable however to access any of the data in shots[i] inside the function (I confirmed this by attempting to print the value of "bulletStruct->x" to the screen for the first 20 and they are all 0 even when it prints fine for the struct in main())

My full Code (on pastebin) for [Main.c](http://pastebin.com/65TAGfDr) and [calculations.c](http://pastebin.com/5b4HCBgf) Its incredibly messy and probably filled with lots of bad practices, since this is my first time coding in (What i believe is C)

Comment: ...What you "believe is C"? Are you unsure of what language you're programming in? Also, please try to add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your questions. Pastebins are fine for a complete code listing, but you should include the relevant parts of your code in the actual question.

Comment: Its hard for me to figure out exactly what I would need to rewrite the code as im unsure of the standard text output or debug output's for c. As I am coding for the 3ds which does not have standard debug output. I am attempting to write a more simplified version of the Issue Im having though that still does the same thing.

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem in the code snippet in the question, and, as you say, the full program is a bit complex to go through. Please try to boil it down further. Most likely you'll run into the solution along the way.

Comment: @JasonBrown `printf(format, ...)` and `fprintf(stderr, format, ...)`

Comment: I cant seem to get the same problem result when I run it in my testing environment.

Comment: The Best Thing I could do was print all my addresses onto the 3ds screen. What I end up with is this.
The ones Inside the function all point to the same Address which means the wrong one. The one inside Main Points to different addresses *tested with 10 addresses inside the function and 10 outside it*

Comment: @Jason Works fine for me: [see live demo](http://rextester.com/LHH1214). My assumption is you're doing something wrong somewhere else. `The ones Inside the function all point to the same Address` makes me think you're looping incorrectly (perhaps you wrote shots[0] instead of shots[i]).

Comment: You write capital letters in normal text. So: -1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be more explicit you can use parens, or you can make sure you are passing the right thing by defining intermediates like:

```
struct bullet currentBullet=player.shots[i];
struct bullet *bp=&currentBullet;
get_alien_collision(bp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your passing of the struct looks fine but in your function you are assigning to bulletStruct rather than testing equivalence.

```
if ((bulletStruct->x = alienPPositionx + x)&&(bulletStruct->y = alienPPositiony + y))
```

Should probably read

```
if ((bulletStruct->x == alienPPositionx + x)&&(bulletStruct->y == alienPPositiony + y))
```

One way to catch this is declaring the function with const parameters

```
void function ( struct bullet const* bulletStruct)...
```